# Django 3 multiple forms in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django, I am trying to build multiple forms that will be in multiple class based views

my forms.py looks like this

```
from django import forms
from .models import Photo


class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )

class NewContactForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

And I was hoping for my view to be something like:

```
...
from app_workflow.forms import PhotoForm, NewContactForm

class NewContactView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
    def post(self, request):
        form = NewContactForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)

class DragAndDropUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

However, when I add NewContactForm into the import of myapp.forms

from app_workflow.forms import PhotoForm, NewContactForm

I get the error:

> from app_workflow.forms import PhotoForm, NewContactForm ImportError:
> cannot import name 'NewContactForm' from 'app_workflow.forms'

So i am not sure what is the best way to bring and be able to use that second form?

Comment: you need to mention the meta class with model and fields.

Comment: @ngawang13 could you specify more please? I dont understand, what exactly I need to add, and why the Photo form will still work without it? thanks

Comment: which model are you referring the newContactForm to

Comment: @ngawang13 Not referring to a model just a custom form

Comment: Meta class is a ModelForm subclass. A model form has to have a model to work from, and the Meta object configures this. As you have done in your PhotoForm.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this command?

```
from .forms import *
```

Comment: I dont get the error with that, hwoever the form doesnt work when I try submmitting the form. The form does work when I leave it as from .models import Photo

Comment: i didnt get your point, can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: can you give a more complete (working) code example

Answer (score 0):

Once Check weather your app_name is correct or not

Or use this command

```py
from .forms import PhotoForm, NewContactForm
```

Comment: The name is perfect, so that is not the issue, I did try your suggestion but I get the same error with your option

Comment: Where are you rendering the templates where you can display the form ?